# No runnable methods when running JUnit suite test

Tags: java, testing, junit, intellij-idea

I am very new to java testing using `Intellij` `JUnit` plugin. I want to use some `JUnit Suite`, so I copied some code

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(value={KruskalTest.class})
class KruskalTestSuite {}
```

in other file

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class JunitTestSuiteRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(KruskalTestSuite.class);
        for (Failure fail : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(fail.toString());
        }
        if (result.wasSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("All tests finished successfully...");
        }
    }

}
```

and then 
    import junit.framework.TestCase;

```
public class KruskalTest extends TestCase {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testMain() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("hello", "hello");

    }
}
```

the problem is that when I run this code I get this exception

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:169)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:104)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: Wich version of JUnit are you using

Comment: JunitTestSuiteRunner is obsolete and not used. Your tests are started by IntelliJ's JUnit4IdeaTestRunner. How to you start your test?

Answer (score 0):

org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner

```
protected void validateInstanceMethods(List<Throwable> errors) {
        validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(After.class, false, errors);
        validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(Before.class, false, errors);
        validateTestMethods(errors);

        if (computeTestMethods().size() == 0)
            errors.add(new Exception("No runnable methods"));
    }
```

Your code passes all validation checks. It executes fine.

Just a note, you need not extend TestCase when using Annotation.

Comment: It doesn't execute fine. JUnit cannot find any tests to execute.

Comment: @JamesB It runs fine on my end. Most likely its gonne be version related.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing the test suite to JUnitCore, you need to pass the test class.

So change:

```
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(KruskalTestSuite.class);
```

to:

```
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(KruskalTest.class);
```

Comment: His code actually works perfectly fine on my end with passing the TestSuite to JUnitCore

Comment: @Arno_Geismar thanks for the -1. I still think my suggested change will solve this problem.

Comment: Well the thing is he only wants to define the classes in KruskalTestSuite.class once and then be able to run that suite instead of having to specify the classes seperately in JUnitCore.runClasses(). By saying just specify all the classes seperatly you essentially are saying don't use the Suite class. Thus circumventing his problem but not solving it

Comment: @Arno_Geismar Don't agree. The runClasses method expects an array of test classes, not a test suite. The change I have suggested should solve the OP's problem, making minimalistic changes to his existing code. Arguing over how to run the tests is a separate issue - on this I agree with you, running a suite is better.

Comment: take a look at this tutorial. It is his exact same code. The runClasses method can and will run fine with a class which has the @runwith and @Suite.SuiteClasses({// your test classes}) annotations on it. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_suite_test.htm

Comment: @Arno_Geismar Interesting, the code would suggest it is looking for test classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57499/discussion-between-arno-geismar-and-jamesb).